# Is there an equivalent of Vacuum command of SQLite in LiteDB?

Tags: c#, .net, litedb

Is there an equivalent of Vacuum command of SQLite in LiteDB?

> The VACUUM command rebuilds the database file, repacking it into a minimal amount of disk space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `shrink` is the equivalent command you can use to achieve it in LiteDB.

Comment: Yes, Shrink create another database (in memory/temp disk) and copy all data from source to destination.